# Grouping multiple column values in barplot with R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset called Flt

```
CARRIER   CANCELLED  DIVERTED
 UA          0          0
 UA          1          0
 UA          0          1
 AA          1          0
 AA          0          0
 DL          0          1
 DL          1          0
```

I want to do a barplot like this
[image]

Thing is I just want Cancelled =1 and Diverted=1 in the barplot. I tried using ggplot but I am not sure on how to add the second column.

```
ggplot(data=Flt) + geom_bar(aes(x=CARRIER, fill=c(CANCELLED=1),(DIVERTED=1)),position = "dodge")
```

I get error "stat_count() can only have an x or y aesthetic" when I use the code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for geom_col:

```
pivot_longer(df,2:3) %>% 
  ggplot() + geom_col(aes(x=CARRIER,y=value,fill=name), position="dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you looking for this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-CARRIER) %>%
  filter(value==1) %>%
  group_by(CARRIER,name) %>% summarise(N=sum(value))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=CARRIER,y=N,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge2(0.9,preserve = 'single'),color='black')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code2
df %>% pivot_longer(-CARRIER) %>%
  group_by(CARRIER,name) %>% summarise(N=sum(value==1))%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=CARRIER,y=N,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9),color='black')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(CARRIER = c("UA", "UA", "UA", "AA", "AA", "DL", 
"DL"), CANCELLED = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), DIVERTED = c(0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Your #code2 logic is what I need for another thing I am working on. But i dont understand group_by() and summarize(). The other thing I need is to plot various airports vs dep_delay and arr_delay but it should only count (Diverted = 0) and (Cancelled = 0). I am wondering how will you introduce condition in the code. I tried to put in summarize() but I get error.